# stat command format to append '/' to file name if directory, and remove "./" from front

Tags: bash, find, stat

With the following command I have been able to list all the directories relative to the current directory along with the epoch time last modified:

```
find . -exec stat -c '%n: %Y' {} \;
```

the output looks something like this:

```
.: 1569247414
./a_file.txt: 1561624333
./some_folder: 1561624645
./some_folder/some_file.txt: 1561624645
./some_folder/another_file.txt: 1536557809
```

How would I go about getting rid of the "./" appearing at the beginning of every entry, and add a '/' if it is a directory?

As a bonus, getting rid of the first entry '.' which is just the current folder would be nice.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add `-mindepth 1` to get rid of `.` which is depth==0
- Alternative: use `find *` instead of `find .`
- Separate files from folders with `-type d ... -or -type f ...`
- Use `+` instead of `\;` to send multiple files to `stat`; it can handle it and will be much faster !

---

```
find * \
-type d -exec stat -c '%n/: %Y' {} + \
-or -type f -exec stat -c '%n: %Y' {} +
```

---

**BUT...**

You don't need `-exec stat` at all !

- Use `find`s bultin `-printf` to print the last modification date (`%Cs` would be the equivalent to `stat`'s `%Y`).
- `-printf '%P'` instead of `%p` will also let you get rid of `./` at the beginning of each file name.

---

```
find . -mindepth 1 \
-type d -printf '%P/: %Cs\n' \
-or -type f -printf '%P: %Cs\n'
```

---

**Output:**

```
a_file.txt: 1561624333
some_folder/: 1561624645
some_folder/some_file.txt: 1561624645
some_folder/another_file.txt: 1536557809
```

Comment: Brilliant, a very clean approach. For best performance is it better to use "find path/to/directory" over cd'ing into the directory and using "find ." or "find *"? Also would using -printf be better optimised than stat?

Comment: I don't know, but would say that it doesn't make a big difference...